# Прямая речь и недоговоренные слова

Tags: прямая-речь, несобственно-прямая-речь

Снова прошу помощи у сайта. Вот такое предложение -

*— Да что ты... — "ерунду несёшь", — не договорил Майкл.*

правильно ли оформлена прямая речь, а если нет - как оформить правильно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да держите руку помощи, если

> — Да что ты... — "ерунду несёшь", — не договорил Майкл.

от первого до последнего знака не договаривает Майкл, и только он.

*— Да что ты... ерунду несёшь, — не договорил Майкл.*

Будем думать, что многоточие перед *ерундой* - это некая речевая запинка Майкла, ну, подбор эвфемизма, чтобы смягчить напрашивающуюся быть произнесённой гадость.